# Publish Typescript Interfaces with NPM

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm working in a project that has multiple typescript projects. I'm trying to have a common package for all the interfaces, types, enums, etc.

I thought I could make it work creating a NPM package with Typescript and have an index.ts with this content:

[image: index.ts content]

When I'm working in the projects that depend on this package, everything seems fine, but when I want to start the development environment I'm getting this error:

[image: Error with ts-node/register]

I've got the suggestion of running ts-node with --skipIgnore flag, but I'm getting the same error:

[image: Error with skipIgnore]

Maybe I needed to compile the code and import the .js (doesn't make ANY sense, but at this point ‍♂️)... no luck.

Let me share both tsconfig.json:

The one from the "common" package:

[image: tsconfig from common package]

The one from the project that depends on the common package:

[image: tsconfig from dependant project]

---

### Things suggested and tried:

> Because your target is ES6, commonjs modules cannot use your package. The dependent project should change its module type to ES6 as well - @kellys

Changing project's module to ES6, brings me this error:
[image: Error with ES6]

All right, let's add `moduleResolution: "node"` ... and I'm getting:
[image: Error with moduleResolution:node]

So I'm adding `"type":"module"` in package.json:
[image: Error with type module in package json]

Comment: Because your target is ES6, commonjs modules cannot use your package. The dependent project should change its module type to ES6 as well

Comment: Hi @kellys ! Thanks for your suggestion, please take a look on what happened under "Things suggested and tried"

Comment: When using ES6 you have to provide the file and extension, so for example with that error specifically you need to import from ./src/index.js